# Как добавить ссылку к тексту в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ссылки

работаю над курсовым проектом и возникла необходимость в QLabel с уже имеющимся текстом добавлять ссылку на более развёрнутое описание элемента
Пытаюсь добавить ссылку вот так:

```
self.result_text.setText(self.result_text.text() + '<a href="https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/{1}.html">Узнать больше</a>'.format(1,self.comboBox_CAPEC.currentText()[6:9]))
```

В итоге выводится всё текстом, вместе с тегом a. Подскажите, как сделать это правильно?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример добавления гиперссылки в `QLabel`:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("<a href=\"http://example.com/\">Click Here!</a>")
        self.text.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
        self.text.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)
        self.text.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        vbox.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.resize(200, 100)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, очень помогли!